# How to modify the paginate count in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to know how to disable or modify the paginate count in CakePHP 3.
I reviewed and in CakePHP2 is:

```
function paginateCount ($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra) {
    return 0;
}
```

However, in CakePHP 3 it does not work. I also reviewed the **PaginatorComponent.php** and the **PaginatorHelper.php** but I did not find the solution.
Thanks for the answers.
Happy developments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the [counter function](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records):

```
$query = $query->
    ->counter(function ($query) {
        return 100000;
    }
    …
);
$query->count(); // Returns 100000
```

The functionality to provide a custom count implementation is more generally available on the query now. Just incorporate that when building the paginate.